# Visual C++ memory leak

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a serial communication library I am creating, and it is a managed assembly, which comes with it's own rules (I do not fully understand them, I just change code when VS complains), and I have a memory leak that I cannot figure out.

This is the leak warning that I get (line 11 is the InfoContainer constructor in SerialComm::SerialComm()):

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
SerialComm.cpp(11) : {144} normal block at 0x011468B8, 56 bytes long.
Data: <                > 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
```

This is the .h file for the lib:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <atlstr.h>

public class InfoContainer {
public:
    ~InfoContainer();
    HANDLE handle;
    bool connected;
    COMSTAT status;
    DWORD errors;
    DCB connection_params;
    CStringA port_name;
};

public ref class SerialComm {
public:
    InfoContainer* info=0;
    SerialComm();
    ~SerialComm();
    bool OpenConnection(String^ Portname);
    int CloseConnection();
    bool WriteData(String^ toSend);
    String^ ReadData(int bytesToRead);
};
```

and these are the relevant .cpp sections:

```
SerialComm::SerialComm() {
    info = new (_NORMAL_BLOCK, __FILE__, __LINE__) InfoContainer();
    info->handle = 0;
}
SerialComm::~SerialComm() {
    CloseConnection();
    delete info;
}

bool SerialComm::OpenConnection(String ^ Portname) {
    info->port_name = Portname;

    //visual studio's valgrindish tool
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDOUT);
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();


    info->handle = CreateFileA(
        info->port_name,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL

    );
    if (info->handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        ATLTRACE("Error: %d", GetLastError());
        printf("Error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    //
    //rest of connection code here
    //
}

int SerialComm::CloseConnection() {
    return CloseHandle(info->handle);
}

InfoContainer::~InfoContainer() {
    delete handle;
}
```

The reason I have to use an InfoContainer class and InfoContainer pointer in the main class is that some information I need to store is considered unmanaged code and so I cannot have it directly in the main class.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In VS Watch Window write `_crtBreakAlloc ` that has the value = -1. Now set its value to 144. Then VS should break at the 144 th allocation of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks()` is called before all objects are deleted.

You need a **finalizer**.  Following is the "golden pattern" when you write a class in C++/CLI:

```
virtual ~SerialComm()
{
    this->!SerialComm();
}

!SerialComm()
{
}
```

Don't forget to add **virtual** to your destructor.  The reason why virtual destructor is needed should be explained in any good C++ textbooks.

Comment: I do not understand what I am supposed to be doing.  I made a finalizer, and moved the destructor code into that, then called the finalizer from the destructor, but I am still getting the memory leak, and now I get a SEHException when trying to close the handle.

Comment: Can you show me your *main()* function?  Are you using gcnew?  Also check the compiler option [Configuration Properties] - [C/C++] - [Code Generation] - [Enable C++ Exceptions] for SEHException.

Comment: I am actually compiling this as a managed dll.  I can't use gcnew for the InfoContainer because it contains unmanaged resources.  This is the main: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b24ad9df664cbce9a24bc57548d72dc .

Comment: I checked your main function code.  It's written in C#.  By the way, I found the root cause of the memory leak.  See my revised answer above.